# Trouble using a regex to validate email addresses with double '@'

Tags: regex, validation, email

In order to validate email addresses I am using the following regex 
from [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html):

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

The problem using the above regex is that I can succefully validate also email addresses with double '@' like these:

```
name@surname@gmail.com # Note the double '@'
test@gmail@com.com
```

... *that I don't want*. So, **how can I adjust that?**

---

**UPDATE**

I discover also that regex doesn't refuse email addresses like these:

```
name@gmail
test@surname@gmail
```

Answer (score 3):

Your current regex matches any string that has a valid email in it. Your input string `nome@surname@gmail.com` has a valid email `surname@gmail.com`.

You need to add start anchor(`^`) and end anchor(`$`) to the regex so that the regex matches the **complete** string and not a **proper substring** of it.

Try:

```
^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$
```

Comment: Maybe it is because I get that regex string from a database record using the Ruby on Rails frameworks... I use this syntax to retrieve the value: Regexp.new(Parameter.find_by_param_name('email_regex').param_value)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you "might" be using .net, here's the regex I use for validating email addresses.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})$
```

Comment: I would like to keep that regex.